# Is there an updated form of socket.connect?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

World.

I am having an issue with a TCP client not initiating a connection to a TCP server I have setup.  This is frustrating because I know the .connect is an available option but it fails every time.  I am using Python 3.10.5 and as you see in the code below, I'm using the double (()) for a tuple, which is required for connections(also a single () will not allow you to use a double variable).  Anyway, here's the code, after the code you will see the error.  Thanks much in advance!

```
import socket
target_host = "http://www.google.com"
target_port = 80
# create a socket object
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# connect the client
client.connect((target_host, target_port))
# send some data
client.send(b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: http://www.google.com\r\n\r\n")
# receive some data
response = client.recv(4096)
print(response.decode())
client.close()
```

```
The error I get is:
File "/home/kali/Documents/TCP_CLIENT.py", line 7, in <module>
client.connect((target_host, target_port))
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Comment: use just the host name for target_host, not a URL.

Comment: You could just take out the protocol when inserting the url: `target_host = "www.google.com"`. When I tested it at least, it connected with no errors.